# getHibernateTemplate NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, nullpointerexception, dao

I have a simple application to retrive a data from oracle DB:

```
public class userExportImpl extends HibernateDaoSupport {

    public User getUser (final String username) throws OssObjectNotFoundException, OssIllegalArgumentException
    {
       Session session = null;
       SessionFactory sessionFactory = new
            Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
       session = sessionFactory.openSession();
       User user= null;
       createHibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
       user = (User)getHibernateTemplate().execute( new HibernateCallback()
       {
          public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException
          {
            User user = (User) session.get(User.class, username);

            return user;
          }
       });
    session.close();
    return user;
}}
```

Here's the main() where i call getUser:

```
public class userExportTool {
public static void main(String args[]){
   userExportImpl userExport = new userExportImpl();
   User user = userExport.getUser("test");
}}
```

And that's the exception i get when i try to run it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.tektronix.userExport.userExportImpl.getUser(userExportImpl.java:40)
    at com.tektronix.userExport.uacnExportTool.main(uacnExportTool.java:17)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

At first i thought that getHibernateTemplate requires a session factory and opened session, so i added those, but still i receive a nullPointerException and i don't have a clue why that happens.
Both hibernate.cfg.xml and User.hbm.xml are present and i already tried working with db by simpler methods like session.get(), so connection must be fine.
Can you please give me some ideas?

Comment: You should really read the Spring documentation, because you don't use it correctly. The session factory should be created by Spring, not by the DAO. The DAO should be created by Spring, not by the main method. The session factory should be injected in the DAO. You shouldn't open and close sessions, but let Spring do it for you based on the transactional context.

Comment: I suppose you are right. For the purpose of this example i used more simple approach and used 'session.get()'. Can you recommend a good book on spring and hibernate for beginners?

Comment: No. I learnt by reading their official documentation.